# Spreading silicone caulk thin?

Tags: silicone

I'm using silicone as an impromptu paint/varnish (the object to be varnished can and will flex in ways typical varnish won't survive).

I've used a bit of cardboard as a spatula to mild results - not terrible, but not exceptionally smooth. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: How big is this object and what is it made from? How regular is the surface? There may be better choices.

Comment: It's not too large, but it has some curious curves. It's basically a sword's handguard.

Comment: Might be better off with plasti-dip. It stays highly flexible and is easy to brush on, or you can get it in a spray can. Comes in lots of colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ideas: A plastic putty knife, or a shower squeegee.

Plastic disposable putty knifes are sold in most paint sections and are cheap and somewhat flexible.  I've seen them up to 6" wide.

Another common item would be a rubber-edged squeegee commonly sold to dry off glass showers to prevent water spotting.  The flexible rubber might make it hard to control the thickness of the silicone, but it seems like it would be worth a try.